# Why doesn't the process exit during this unittest with dart:io?

Tags: debugging, dart

The following code tests the received datas on a server sent by a client.

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';

main() {
  ServerSocket ss;

  setUp(() => ServerSocket.bind('localhost', 9876).then((e) => ss = e));

  tearDown(() => ss.close());

  test('test 1', () {
    final line = new Completer<String>();
    ss.listen((s) => s.map(UTF8.decode).listen((s) => line.complete(s)));
    Socket.connect(ss.address, ss.port)
        .then((s) {
          s.write('test');
          return s.close();
        })
        .then((_) => line.future)
        .then(expectAsync((s) => expect(s, equals('test'))));
  });
}
```

This test displays:

```
unittest-suite-wait-for-done
PASS: test 1

All 1 tests passed.
unittest-suite-success
```

However, the process doesn't stop.

1. Why the process is still running even with the `ss.close()` and `s.close()`?
2. How to find what makes the process stay alive? Does [Observatory](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/observatory/) provide something to debug that ?

Comment: There is an open issue to support debugging such issues http://dartbug.com/21674

Comment: Maybe similar to http://dartbug.com/20833#c4

Comment: There is a tool for debugging this. See here https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/misc/UkCxbpSbdXA/I8FRDlKRZmwJ

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27024868 for how to debug the event queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: See Alex's answer below. Socket.drain() FTW!

According to the [observatory io page](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/misc/UkCxbpSbdXA/I8FRDlKRZmwJ), the socket created by the server was still open for writing. I've updated the code below to call [destroy()](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:io.Socket#id_destroy) on both the server and client socket. [destroy()](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:io.Socket#id_destroy) closes a [Socket](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:io.Socket) in both directions.

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';

main() {
  ServerSocket ss;

  setUp(() => ServerSocket.bind('localhost', 9876).then((e) => ss = e));

  tearDown(() => ss.close());

  test('test 1', () {
    final line = new Completer<String>();
    ss.listen((s) {
      s.map(UTF8.decode).listen((t) {
        line.complete(t);
        s.destroy();
      });
    });
    Socket.connect(ss.address, ss.port)
        .then((s) {
          s.write('test');
          return s.flush().then((_) {
            s.destroy();
            return line.future;
          });
        })
        .then(expectAsync((s) => expect(s, equals('test'))));
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Greg. It was not really obvious that `close()` was only closing the writing stream (this behaviour of [`close()`](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:io.Socket#id_close) is only described on [`destroy()`](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:io.Socket#id_destroy) :-/ ).

Comment: It's tripped me up a few times as well. Perhaps it's worth filing a bug, either the documentation needs to be improved or the api made simpler. I also would have thought that calling close() once in the server and once in the client should have been enough, but it is not. Would be nice to get a better answer from someone familiar with the implementation details.

Comment: I agree. I expected that `close()` has the `destroy()` behaviour. From an api point of view I would like to have something like `close({bool writing: true, bool reading: true})`

Comment: I assume it's because Socket implements IOSink which has close(). So I'm not sure that would be possible. Perhaps post on the mailing list, and see if Anders can shed some light on this. Maybe there is a simpler way to do this, and I'm missing something.

Comment: I think using destroy() should be a last resort, and closing both ends of the socket should be enough.  If both destroy() calls are replaced with close(), and an s.drain() is added after the s.write(), then the s.flush can also be removed.This is a better solution, because it does exactly what is needed for a connection to terminate and disappear: Both ends must be closed, and both ends must be listened to.

Comment: Thanks, could you please explain why s.flush().then((_) => s.close()) causes the socket to remain open. I don't understand this.

Comment: Thanks Greg and William. I added an answer with some comments. I keep on thinking that `drain()` should be called by `close()` because it's really not obvious you have to call 2 methods to close a Socket.

Answer (score 1):

According to [William comment on the answer of Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28159029/why-doesnt-the-process-exit-during-this-unittest-with-dartio#comment44705251_28163134) `drain()` and `close()` should be prefered instead of `destroy()`.

Here is the working version:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';

main() {
  ServerSocket ss;

  setUp(() => ServerSocket.bind('localhost', 9876).then((e) => ss = e));

  tearDown(() => ss.close());

  test('test 1', () {
    final line = new Completer<String>();
    ss.listen((s) => UTF8.decodeStream(s)
                         .then((value) => line.complete(value))
                         .then((_)=> s.close()));
    Socket.connect(ss.address, ss.port)
        .then((s) {
          s.write('test');
          return Future.wait([s.drain(), s.close()]);
        })
        .then((_) => line.future)
        .then(expectAsync((s) => expect(s, equals('test'))));
  });
}
```

Some comments on this:

- on the server side I used `UTF8.decodeStream(s).then(...)` instead of `s.map(UTF8.decode).listen(...)` because the value could be splitted in several chunks. In this case the socket would be closed too earlier.
- on the client side I used `Future.wait([s.drain(), s.close()])` instead of chaining Futures. If I use `s.drain().then((_) => s.close())` the process blocks because the server is waiting for the end of data stream (triggered by `s.close()` on client side) to close the Socket and thus trigger the completation of the `s.drain()` on client side.